# ValueError: Unknown regularizer: AdaptiveL1L2

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model, google-colaboratory

I am loading a pre-trained model in **Google Colab** using **TensorFlow, Keras**.
I have written the following code for this purpose:

```
from keras.models import load_model 
model = load_model('/content/gdrive/model.h5')
```

But I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-34df1d0b8dd9> in <module>()
      1 from keras.models import load_model
----> 2 model = load_model('/content/gdrive/model.h5')

22 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in class_and_config_for_serialized_keras_object(config, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
    294   cls = get_registered_object(class_name, custom_objects, module_objects)
    295   if cls is None:
--> 296     raise ValueError('Unknown ' + printable_module_name + ': ' + class_name)
    297 
    298   cls_config = config['config']

ValueError: Unknown regularizer: AdaptiveL1L2
```

What am I doing wrong, here? I am new to Keras, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to pass it as a custom object when loading the model.

Comment: What information do you have on the pretrained model? Which keras version produced it, does it use any custom objects?

Comment: @Frightera Are you saying like this: `model = load_model('/content/gdrive/model.h5', custom_objects={"AdaptiveL1L2": AdaptiveL1L2})` ? It gives error too: `NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-c71895e61195> in <module>()
----> 1 model = tf.saved_model.load("/content/gdrive/model.h5", custom_objects={"AdaptiveL1L2": AdaptiveL1L2})

NameError: name 'AdaptiveL1L2' is not defined`

Comment: @user14: Yes. I meant that. Seems like you did not define the function.

Comment: @Frightera I'll try to define the function and update you, if it works.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Currently I am using tensorflow 2.4.1. By custom objects you mean as suggested by @Frightera?